# Function does not return anything

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class Test {
  public id: number; public name: string; public fid: number
};

export const TESTS: Test[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Cat', fid: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'Dog', fid: 1},
  {id: 3, name: 'Elephant', fid: 1},
  {id: 4, name: 'Bird', fid: 1},
  {id: 5, name: 'Duck', fid: 2},
  {id: 6, name: 'Snake', fid: 2},
  {id: 7, name: 'Rabbit', fid: 2},
  {id: 8, name: 'Dolphin', fid: 2},
  {id: 9, name: 'Sheep', fid: 3},
  {id: 10, name: 'Cow', fid: 3},
  {id: 11, name: 'Fish', fid: 3},
  {id: 12, name: 'Monkey', fid: 3}];

let testsPromise = Promise.resolve(TESTS);

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  getTests(id) { 
    let items: Test[] = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < TESTS.length; i++) {
        if(TESTS[i].fid == id) { 
        items.push(TESTS[i]) 
        }
    }
    return items;
 }
}
```

It seems that TESTS is unreachable in funciton getTests(id),
but testsPromise is available because i receive all data if do return testsPromise in getTests function. Why?

Comment: Then what it's returning? `undefined` or `[]` etc..?

Comment: tru to put a public in front of  getTests(id:number)

Comment: if i do return TESTS it return all, it means that function is reachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `Test` an interface like this?

```
interface Test {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    fid: number;
}
```

If so, you must initialize `items` array before the loop begins (note the use of `let`):

```
getTests(id: number) {
    let items: Test[] = [];
    // ...
}
```

Then, make sure that `TESTS`, wherever it is declared, is *available* within the function:

```
getTests(id: number) {
    console.log(TESTS); // do you see this output?
    // ...
}
```

With the above set, your code worked **fine** for me.

---

Bonus: if you want further refinement, you can rewrite your function in one line:

```
getTests(id: number): Test[] {
    return TESTS.filter((oneTest: Test) => oneTest.fid === id);
}
```

Comment: Then, make sure that TESTS, wherever it is declared, is available within the function

It doesn't available in that function:(
But why? They are in one file.

let testPromise = Promise.resolve(TESTS);
but this is availableto return.
return testPromise

Comment: Are you doing the `import` of it at the top of the file? Something like `import { TESTS } from 'the-tests-file';`.

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
export class Test {
  public id: number; public name: string; public fid: number
}
export const TESTS: Test[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Cat', fid: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'Dog', fid: 1},
  {id: 3, name: 'Elephant', fid: 1},
  {id: 4, name: 'Bird', fid: 1},
  {id: 5, name: 'Duck', fid: 2},
  {id: 6, name: 'Snake', fid: 2}
];

Comment: let testsPromise = Promise.resolve(TESTS);

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  getTests(id) { 
    let items: Test[] = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < TESTS.length; i++) {
        if(TESTS[i].fid == id) { 
        items.push(TESTS[i]) 
        }
    }
    return items;
 }

}

Comment: Are you doing the import of it at the top of the file? Something like import { TESTS } from 'the-tests-file';   They are in one file

Comment: Update your question with the whole file. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: Bonus: if you want further refinement, you can rewrite your function in one line:

getTests(id: number): Test[] {
    return TESTS.filter((oneTest: Test) => oneTest.fid === id);
}


Can you advise me where i can read about this?It is very nice.

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize items:

```
  var items: Test[] = [];
```

Comment: The same result, i didn't receive anything.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.service.geTests(+params['id']))
          .subscribe(tests => this.tests = tests);

if i do as you write, i have notification, that:
Type Test is not assignable to type Test[]